# opencv pixel locations

Tags: python, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have an image that looks like this:
[image: Skeleton Image]

From this image, I want to get a list of all of the pixel locations for pixels which are nonzero (white).  I'm using OpenCV in Python, and I don't have a good sense of how.

Thanks,
Bradley Powers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10629/opencv-pixel-locations/) by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 422 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you haven't already, I'd suggest looking at NumPy for manipulating your OpenCV images in Python. If you load your images as CvMat objects instead of IplImages then you can manipulate them as NumPy objects without copying the data.

NumPy takes a while to get your head around, but once you do you can use techniques such as the ones given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487437/coordinates-of-item-on-numpy-array) to achieve what you want.

Based on that, running this program

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import cv
import numpy

cvImg = cv.LoadImageM( "testImage.png",     # Must use LoadImageM
    iscolor=cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )
npImg = numpy.asarray( cvImg )  # No copying takes place

coordList = numpy.argwhere( npImg == 255 )
numWhitePoints = len( coordList )

print coordList
print "Found {0} points".format( numWhitePoints )
```

on your image should output like this

```
[[ 97 318]
 [ 97 322]
 [ 97 323]
   .. ..
   .. ..
 [141 200]
 [146 189]
 [153 178]]
Found 216 points
```

---

Originally posted by [abroun](https://answers.ros.org/users/850/abroun/) with karma: 113 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4